# How do I automatically update the latest block number and pending txns in my app?

Tags: web3.py, infura

I wish to make a simple application using KivyMD. I want to display the latest block and pending txns on the ethereum blockchain and have it update automatically with every new block. I'm using infura url and web3.py.

```
pending_block = web3.eth.getBlock(block_identifier='pending', full_transactions=True)
pending_transactions = pending_block['transactions']
```

What do I do to make the app automatically get this every time a new block originates? Listeners? Websockets? Or use a while loop that sleeps for a specified time and calls a function to fetch the latest data?

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-pendingtransactions might help.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain so this will automatically send me every new pending txn? Would this have to go in an infinite while loop to be called recurrently? Also this is a JS library. I'm looking for Python.

Comment: There is very likely the equivalent in the python module. Check the documentation for events. I have not used it, but i think you do not need a loop. You will probably have to assign a callback/method to execute whenever an event is found. Try it out.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain I suspect that would require Infura's websocket and not HTTP request.

Comment: Please RTFM: https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/wss/eth-subscribe

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to blockchain events. From Web3js [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-newblockheaders):

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders', function(error, result){
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);

        return;
    }

    console.error(error);
})
.on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
    console.log(subscriptionId);
})
.on("data", function(blockHeader){
    console.log(blockHeader);
})
.on("error", console.error);

// unsubscribes the subscription
subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
    if (success) {
        console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's JS. I need a python equivalent.

Comment: Just check Python counterpart. Concept is the same, implemention is just a detail.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code help you. It contains recursive function.

```
def checkBlockNumber(blockNumber = None):
    if blockNumber:
        if blockNumber == w3.eth.get_block_number():
            time.sleep(1)
            checkBlockNumber(blockNumber)
    else:        
        return w3.eth.get_block_number()

while True:
    block_number = checkBlockNumber()
    print(block_number)
    checkBlockNumber(block_number)
```